# NIOSH 7300 - ICP OES calculation

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration

need some help with NIOSH 7300 method https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/docs/2003-154/pdfs/7300.pdf

I have two 37mm cellulose filter paper, one is my filter blank while other is sample. The sample has 80L of natural gas passed through and I plan to test for Mg , final concentration in mg/kg.

Both are digested and top up to 10 ml with dilution acid.

ICP OES Result:

Filter Blank : Mg = 0.022 mg/L , Pb = 0.002 mg/L

Sample       : Mg = 0.038 mg/L , Pb = 0.006 mg/L

---

(From Method) 
Given the formula is

Solution concentrations for the sample, Cs(µg/mL),

Filter blank , Cb(µg/mL)

Volumes of sample, Vs(mL), and Filter blank , Vb(mL),

calculate the concentration,C (mg/m3), of each element in the air volume sampled, V (L):

C= (CsVs - CbVb)/V = mg/m3

NOTE: µg/L / mg/m3

---

My calculation,

[(0.038 mg/L x 0.01 L) - (0.022 mg/L X 0.01 L)]/ 80L

= 0.00016 mg/ 80L

Edit:

According to the composition result, density is = 17 gmol-1 , 
and I calculate this under STP.

= 0.00016 mg / [(80/22.4)mol * (0.017kg/mol)]

= 0.00263 mg/Kg

is this correct?

Comment: You need density of the gas at the " pumping through filter" conditions.